# Twisted: How to find the final destination in case of HTTP 301?

Tags: python, web, twisted, http-status-code-301, redirect

In case of a `url` that redirects with `HTTP 301`, `twisted.web.client.getPage` successfully emulates the browser's behaviour and returns a `deferred` that fires with the `html` / `response_body` of the final destination. How do I get the `url` of this destination page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `twisted.web.client.Agent` to perform a `HEAD` request in order to retrieve the `Location` header which is the URL you are looking for.

See https://github.com/darkrho/Random-Code/blob/master/python/twisted/longurl.py

The `LocationResolver` class performs a `HEAD` request and calls the callback with the value of the `Location` header. This only retrieve the first redirection, if you want to find the final URL you can follow what `handleResult` does, that is calling resolver again until you don't get a new location value.